# Passing a variable from a Navigation Bar choice

Tags: php, html, navigation

At the moment I have a PHP/HTML select box that is created dynamically from database variables. I use $_POST to recognise the selection, and process it accordingly.

What I want to do is move this into a nav bar drop down menu. I can build the nav bar from the database OK. But is it possible to send all the nav bar lines to the same href BUT also send a value indicating which one was chosen?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be understanding the question, but I presume you're asking how you can have a bunch of items link to the same URL but also send a hidden cue via POST as well? (I'm guessing you don't like the idea of using _GET vars in the URL?)

You can try using JS to fake the links for you. When a user clicks, instead of having the element they click be a real link, simply have it submit a form or use AJAX to submit _POST vars to the receiving page.

For a form, the links in the navbar would look like (using crude inline js):

```
<a href="#nolink" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_input_name_in_hidden_form').value='custom value'; document.getElementById('form_name').submit()">Link</a>
```

and the form would just be

```
<form action="[the shared url" name='form_name' method='post' style='display:none'>
<input type='hidden' name='hidden_input_name_in_hidden_form' value='' />
</form>
```

If you were to use AJAX, I'd suggest jquery to handle the POST.

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for your prompt and impressive answer! You and I are only just speaking the same language, and I'm getting about half of what you've written :) Essentially, the aim is this. I have a page which displays hundreds of items stored in a MySQL database and categorised into groups and sub-groups. (They're sentences for teacher reports, incidentally.) At present, users can choose which category to view using a select box & submit button. The $_POST value is processed in PHP and the page redisplayed. Instead, I want to list the categories in a drop down menu. Outta room. Hold on...

Comment: Maybe using _GET vars in the URL is best - I don't know how to do this, mind you. Or maybe the JS method is better, but this is currently beyond my limited skillset too! I don't quite follow how to implement your JS solution. In particular, I don't get why I'm using a form. Sorry for the remedial questions :)

Comment: _GET vars are frequently used in these situations (that's when you stick the variable in the url, so it looks like:
http://example.com/common_script.php?var1=x&var2=y

Comment: Yep, just researching it now. I've always used the db or $_POST, so I'd forgotten about it :) Thanks,.

Comment: The use of a form in my example was just a way that you could have "links" that when clicked would send variables by _POST instead, by having a form submit the variables to the example 'common_script.php', which would keep the variables hidden from the user. My form example was just to show how it could be done, though using ajax (which can also use POST) would be much simpler... In any case, can you post the HTML output that you have right now (what does the drop-down look like)

Comment: Thanks for all this. I'll try a few options. I'd vote up your contribution except you need 15 reputation to do so. BTW, did you -1 my initial question? I looked for about half an hour before I posted it. Anyway, I'm -2 on this effort. Not that I mind, but it's not that encouraging to keep trying to learn!

Comment: Wasn't me, though I can see why it was down-voted... I think that the "nav bar drop down menu" piece was a little difficult to follow (the drop-down output code would help) and lack of clarity is often penalized. In any case, keep it up... it won't take too long rack up some points (one +1 is worth a lot more reputation than one -1 on here)